# Button with popup showed below

Tags: button, popup, javafx

I want to create specific component in JavaFX. Button which show poupup after onClick event.

Scnenario:

1. We click button
2. Popup Shows below button (like on the picture)

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? How's the progress?

Comment: Only class extended Button which show a popup but in wrong place (not below button)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX 2 custom popup pane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717969/javafx-2-custom-popup-pane)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After answering this, I realized it was a duplicate of [JavaFX 2 custom popup pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717969/javafx-2-custom-popup-pane), which has a bit more context info in some of the answers.

Use a [MenuButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) and in a menuItem attached to the MenuButton, set a graphic for the content you want to display in your popup.

```
final MenuItem wizPopup = new MenuItem();
wizPopup.setGraphic(wizBox);

final MenuButton popupButton = new MenuButton("frobozz");
popupButton.getItems().setAll(
  wizPopup            
);
```

Here is a complete, [executable sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5217750).

[image: wizup]