# show a popup window when an event is occured javafx

Tags: popup, javafx

I want to open a popup dialog when a 'signup' button is clicked. I want to add elements like textfield, password field on the pop up dialog. It would be better if you can suggest me how to add components to a popup window and then add the pop window to a pane and show it. 
Thank you!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX 2 custom popup pane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717969/javafx-2-custom-popup-pane)

Comment: I solved the problem. I made a Popup object and added it to a pane having the form components which was made using scenebuilder. This is what I had done at the fxml controller file:-

    `code`
    public void popup()
    {
    @FXML
    Pane popup_pane; //id of the pane which is created at scene     builder
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.show(popup_pane,500,500); //providing x and y points are manditory
    popup_pane.setVisible(true);
    }
    `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make one :

```
Popup pop = PopupBuilder.create().content(contentNode).width(50).height(100).autoFix(true).build();
pop.show(stage);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just make a new Stage, then add desired components to it. For example:

```
public static void showStage(){
Stage newStage = new Stage();
VBox comp = new VBox();
TextField nameField = new TextField("Name");
TextField phoneNumber = new TextField("Phone Number");
comp.getChildren().add(nameField);
comp.getChildren().add(phoneNumber);

Scene stageScene = new Scene(comp, 300, 300);
newStage.setScene(stageScene);
newStage.show();
}
```

Call the method from the main and see that a new stage pops up.

Comment: How did you do that a model popup