# using javafx 8 (java 8 install) How to extend Label.setTooltip Display time to 20secs (while mouse is inside Tooltip)

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip, delay

I have tried Using 
1)
import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(20000);
at various locations in *.java file (using NetBeans IDE)

2) Creating OnMouseEnter MouseEvent Handler Override routine including:
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(20000);

Results: No Errors, Runs fine, Except Display Time is ALWAYS 5secs!!!

I would prefer NOT creating my own Popup Control, because I like all the Behavior of existing Tooltip, except Im trying to Display Several words in Tooltips that User Needs to take Long Time to Read.  Please Help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a Swing utility class, i.e. import javax.**swing**.ToolTipManager, this has no control over JavaFX functionality.

According to [control JavaFX Tooltip delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854301/control-javafx-tooltip-delay), this is not supported and the subject of a change request. That question also contains a reflection based 'hack' and another workaround involving popups.