# Set custom duration for tooltips in JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip, scenebuilder

I'm looking for a solution for the following problem:
I've built up a `javafx GUI` with `SceneBuilder` and added `tooltips` to some of the labels I added.

However, the `tooltips` automatically hide after ~5 seconds. Sometimes this is not enough for the user to read the `tooltips` whole content. I would like to show the `tooltip` as long as the cursor stays above the label and completely disable this `autoHide` function.

I did not find a way to customize the time a popup is shown or how to disable the auto hide function completely. 
Has somebody solved this or a similar problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JavaFX 9 you can set the [`showDuration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#showDurationProperty) (and `showDelay`) property:

```
tooltip.setShowDuration(Duration.seconds(10));
```

or in FXML

```xml
<Tooltip text="Some text">
    <showDuration>
        <Duration millis="10000" />
    </showDuration>
</Tooltip>
```

You can also configure this using CSS: the following

```css
.tooltip {
    -fx-show-duration: 10s ;
}
```

in an external CSS file will set the show duration to 10 seconds for all tooltips. (And obviously you can set style classes and/or ids on the tooltip to create more specific CSS selectors.)

There is no API for this in earlier versions of JavaFX.

Comment: Thank you very much - it took me some time to migrate to JAVA 9 but now it works fine ;)